# Tableau Server On Remote Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

We have deployed a tableau server on a Remote Desktop in an offline mode. Now when the business is trying to access the tableau they get a message that only 2 users can sign in at the same time.

We have more than 50 users who need to access the reports and more than 2-4 need to login simultaneously. What are the option we have.

As this is an offline mode deployment, can we give them some URL or anything else they can access the reports from.

Comment: How many users is your Tableau Server licensed for?

Comment: we initially have 10 server licenses which will move to 100+. The issues was the IT folks had not whitelisted this website as a safe site to be used. The issue has been resolved after they performed this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website and ip we had shared had to be white-listed and added to the safe sites by the IT group policy. 
Adding answer as someone may also come across the same scenario.